# Regular expression take correct number of brackets

Tags: c#, regex

```
\w+\(([^\)]*)?\)+
```

This regex will match

```
abc(1,3,abs(4) 
foo(1,3,abs(4)))
```

I want to match only

```
abc(1,3,abs(4))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21080/In-Depth-with-RegEx-Matching-Nested-Constructions

Comment: I think OP means.. validating paranthesis.. :)

Comment: ...and a look at [regular-expressions.info - Matching Nested Constructs with Balancing Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[a-z]+\((?>[^()]+|\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>))*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)$
```

It will match any string of characters from a to z in the beginning, and then a matching number of parentheses and everything inside them.

[A demo on regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5C((%3F%3E%5B%5E()%5D%2B%7C%5C((%3F%3CDEPTH%3E)%7C%5C)(%3F%3C-DEPTH%3E))*(%3F(DEPTH)(%3F!))%5C)%24&i=foo(1%2C3%2Cabs(4)))%0D%0Aabc(1%2C3%2Cabs(4)%0D%0Aabc(1%2C3%2Cabs(4))&o=m)

Tested in Expresso:

[image]

Comment: @FantomaDinUmbra: If it works for you, please consider accepting the answer.